# how to fetch data from body

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

i have this data in my body section

```
(
[tags] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [tag_id] => 70
                [tag_slug] => step-by-step-macintosh-training
                [tag_name] => step-by-step-macintosh-training
                [tag_description] => 
                [contact_count] => 4
                [show_as_preference] => 0
            )

    )

[status] => success
)
```

i have to fetch tag_id and tag_slug from this body to fetch these two details i used this code:

```
foreach ($body as $key => $value) {
                $tags[] = array('tag_id'=>$value->tag_id,'tag_name'=>$values->tag_name);
        return $tags;
    }
```

but it didn't work it gives black output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [tag_id] => 
        [tag_name] => 
    )

)
```

what's wrong I am doing here? please guide how can I fetch tag_id and tag_slug from body I got in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the structure of the data you have shown, your code doesn't work because you're trying to access tag elements as if they are objects, when they are in fact arrays. Try this instead:

```
$tags = array();
foreach ($body['tags'] as $tag) {
    $tags[] = array('tag_id'=>$tag['tag_id'], 'tag_name'=>$tag['tag_name']);
}
print_r($tags);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag_id] => 70
            [tag_name] => step-by-step-macintosh-training
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/M866V)

Answer (score 0):

You are try to get a array value as object try the following code :

```
foreach ($body as $key => $value) {
    $tags[] = array('tag_id'=>$value['tag_id'],'tag_name'=>$values['tag_name']);

}
return $tags;
```